# MySQL Trigger with IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create my first MYSQL trigger, when an Inserted record with a role_id of 4 is inserted, I want it to insert another record using the same values but with a role_id of 5.

My best effort is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER auto_insert_member
AFTER INSERT ON staff_role
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.role_id = 4) THEN 
        INSERT INTO staff_role
        SET 
          start_date = NEW.start_date,
          end_date = NEW.end_date,
          person_id = NEW.person_id,
          role_id = 5
    END IF
END
```

I can't make it work and phpMyAdmin error messages are not helpful. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A trigger in MySQL cannot act on the table which caused it to fire.  You should probably handle this from your business logic instead.

Comment: you are missing `;` after `set`

Comment: If anyone wants to see Tim's error in action . . .  http://rextester.com/UXDM71491.

Comment: *"phpMyAdmin error messages are not help"* -- The error message this will generate is extremely helpful and on point. It is very clear and understandable, so I can't imagine how anyone would not understand exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps a brief explanation about the limitation would help... if it was allowed, you could very easily think of a scenario in which the first insert would _trigger_ an endless recursion that would bring your DB down its knees.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that the syntax error is due to the mixing of the UPDATE and INSERT method:

```
UPDATE TABLE
   SET COLUM1 = VALUE1,
       COLUM2 = VALUE2;

INSERT INTO TABLE 
       (COLUM1, COLUM2) 
VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE2);
```

Comment: MySQL does not allow to act on the same table that caused the trigger to fire.

Comment: `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` is an Oracle thing. But the question is clearly about MySQL, which is not implementing such a feature. You're right about the wrong `INSERT` syntax though.